# Speed up LP program with Cplex callbacks

Tags: cplex

I've got a Cplex program in which I'm searching for an optimal solution. Unfortunately my Cplex is working too slowly. 
Before running Cplex, I can use some heuristic in order to get relatively good solution.

**Question:** 
How can I use this knowledge (i.e., knowing a good solution) to speed up by program?

**Solution attempt:** 
I'm trying to use Cplex.start.set_start (from CPLEX Python API). However, I don't know how to introduce my variables.

For example, among other variables I have: x1p3 = 0 and x7p2 = 1.

I looked at the set_start definition at the as follows: set_start(self, col_status, row_status, col_primal, row_primal, col_dual, row_dual), but it is not helping me in understanding the problem.

Comment: Which API are you using (e.g., C++, Java, etc.)? For example, with the C++ API, you can use [IloCplex.setStart](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex.html#method_setStart). Under the hood, this uses the [CPXcopystart](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/cpxapi/copystart.html) method in the C Callable Library.

Comment: I'm using Python

Comment: With the CPLEX Python API you can use [Cplex.start.set_start](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.InitialInterface-class.html#set_start) to provide a starting solution for an LP model. For a MIP model (a model with integer variables), you would use [Cplex.MIP_starts.add](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.MIPStartsInterface-class.html#add).

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you can do before starting to solve your model. However, there is no need to use CPLEX callbacks.

1. You can use a preprocessing algorithm to fix variables in your model

   - There are two types of preprocessing algorithm: *exact* and *heuristic*. The exact preprocessing surely does not affect your optimal solution; on the other hand, the heuristic preprocessing may cut your optimal solution.
2. Using a heuristic to compute good bounds for your problem.

   - Again, you have two types of bounds: *primal* bounds and *dual* bounds. Such bounds can be used to speed-up the branch-and-bound algorithm since it will induce some cuts into your branching tree
   - If you are using a primal heuristic, you can use its solution to provide a so-called *warm start* to CPLEX. It is a different initial solution than the usual one, which also can accelerate your model resolution.

Comment: Is warm start the same as MIP?

Comment: MIP is the definition of the programming model (Mixed Integer Programming). Warm Start is a _convention name_ used for starting your MIP with a good solution previously computed by another algorithm